# Ubuntu 22.04 is crashing on startup after recent upgrade

Tags: boot, gnome, 22.04, crash

My Ubuntu is crashing on startup. I'm not a pro user, if I am posting this in a wrong forum, please correct me.

Here are some details

- Works in recovery mode.
- Works fine if I start in recovery mode, then continue with normal boot.
- `uname -a` result

`Linux alyosha-MS-7D30 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

- I have used `journalctrl --since today` to record full log of a single failed boot session and put it in a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/aleksejs-fomins/0ebfae73bd44cc08780fbf8baf2dc570). Hopefully it helps
- I have found several red bugs in the above list, but googling for them did not yield great results for ubuntu

First one

```
Aug 09 15:51:37 alyosha-MS-7D30 kernel: BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000000
Aug 09 15:51:37 alyosha-MS-7D30 kernel: #PF: supervisor instruction fetch in kernel mode
Aug 09 15:51:37 alyosha-MS-7D30 kernel: #PF: error_code(0x0010) - not-present page
```

Second one

```
Aug 09 15:51:37 alyosha-MS-7D30 systemd-udevd[644]: Worker [653] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
Aug 09 15:51:37 alyosha-MS-7D30 systemd-udevd[644]: 0000:01:00.0: Worker [653] failed
```

Third one

```
Aug 09 15:51:38 alyosha-MS-7D30 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
```

Fourth one

```
Aug 09 15:51:58 alyosha-MS-7D30 gnome-session-binary[1915]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Aug 09 15:51:58 alyosha-MS-7D30 gnome-session-binary[1915]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
```

Fifth one

```
Aug 09 15:51:58 alyosha-MS-7D30 gnome-session-binary[1915]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
```

**Sixth one**. This one is quite important, as it is repeated 3 times with a giant dump, I from my forum readings it is related to Gnome failing to start, but I am not sure.

```
Aug 09 15:51:58 alyosha-MS-7D30 gdm-launch-environment][1868]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Seventh one and related

```
Aug 09 15:51:59 alyosha-MS-7D30 pulseaudio[1882]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="2" name="pci-0000_01_00.1" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1" namereg_fail=false tsch>
Aug 09 15:52:00 alyosha-MS-7D30 pipewire[1880]: spa.alsa: 'iec958:1': capture open failed: Device or resource busy
Aug 09 15:52:00 alyosha-MS-7D30 pipewire[1880]: spa.alsa: 'front:1': playback open failed: No such file or directory
Aug 09 15:52:01 alyosha-MS-7D30 pipewire-media-session[1881]: spa.alsa: The decibel volume range for element 'PCM' (-2837 dB - -6 dB) has negative maximum. Disabling the decibel range.
Aug 09 15:52:01 alyosha-MS-7D30 pipewire-media-session[1881]: spa.alsa: The decibel volume range for element 'PCM' (-2837 dB - -6 dB) has negative maximum. Disabling the decibel range.
Aug 09 15:52:01 alyosha-MS-7D30 pipewire-media-session[1881]: spa.alsa: The decibel volume range for element 'PCM' (-2837 dB - -6 dB) has negative maximum. Disabling the decibel range.
Aug 09 15:52:01 alyosha-MS-7D30 pipewire-media-session[1881]: spa.alsa: The decibel volume range for element 'PCM' (-2837 dB - -6 dB) has negative maximum. Disabling the decibel range.
Aug 09 15:52:01 alyosha-MS-7D30 pipewire-media-session[1881]: spa.alsa: The decibel volume range for element 'PCM' (-2837 dB - -6 dB) has negative maximum. Disabling the decibel range.
```

Could you please advice me how to proceed? I guess I could roll back to a previous kernel or gnome version, but I don't know what sort of rollback do I need and how to do it.

**EDIT**:
I just reverted to the previous kernel version (5.19), and the issues seem to have been solved.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 is EOL.  Search this site for upgrades from obsolete versions.

Comment: My bad, I actually have 22.04. I'm sorry for misinforming people, I'll edit the post.

Comment: I have also been experiencing random crashes after 6.2